# What does the following code do?

Tags: c

```
static void llist_dtor(void *user, void *element)
{
  (void)user;
  (void)element;
  /* Do nothing */
}
```

Is it no-operation function? Then why is casting done? Is it ok to pass NULL as one of its parameters?

Answer (score 15):

That's indeed a no-op. The casts to `(void)` are here to avoid getting "parameter never used" warnings with some compilers (the casts are optimized away, but the parameters are still considered as "used").

You can pass `NULL` since the parameters are ignored anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is a no-op function.

The casting is a common trick to prevent the compiler complaining about unused parameters.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is a no-op function and `void` casted lines are placed to avoid the "unused parameter" warning. For gcc, search for "unused" in the page: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html

However, **if it were C++ instead of C**, I would probably write it little differently as

```
static void llist_dtor( void * /* user */, void * /* element */ )
{
  /* Do nothing */
}
```

Note that the variable names are commented out.

Comment: -1, gcc won't compile C code without argument names. (Works for C++ though).

Comment: @Andrew Medico: +1: Thanks for correcting me. Mostly I do C++ and there I have done this few times... Never thought this could be different in C.

Answer (score 0):

That is not no-op. Like that you tell the compiler to ignore those two arguments.