# C pointer on a pointer : unused variable

Tags: c, pointers

I was just doing my first app in C and i have this **warning** (edited) : `unused variable pp`

```
int compteur =  1;
int *p = &compteur;
int **pp = &p;
```

I was just trying to make `pp` pointing on the adress of the variable `p`

Forgive me if that's a stupid question, but in my book they don't talk about pointers on pointer.
Thanks

Comment: Unless you are telling the compiler to deal with warnings as errors, this case usually produces a warning at best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if that's the only thing your program does, then yes, the compiler is correct to warn you about unused variables, because you're not doing anything with them!

If you were to do e.g. `printf("%d\n", **p);`, then the warning should go away.

Answer (score 3):

That's perfectly legitimate. Your compiler is just informing you that you made a variable, then didn't do anything with it - normally indicating a programming error.

Answer (score 3):

I can suppose, that that's not **error**, but **warning**. "unused variable pp" means, that you just don't use variable pp in further code.

Answer (score 1):

> i have this warning (edited) : unused
>   variable pp

**Kudos for respecting (and worrying and asking) the compiler warning message. Keep that up.** (I always compile with `-Werror` so that "warnings" are treated as "errors." I always find it helpful.)

Quoting from the [gcc warnings page](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html):

> -Wunused-variable
>
> Warn whenever a local variable or non-constant static
>   variable is unused aside from its
>   declaration. This warning is enabled
>   by -Wall.

Strictly speaking, it does make sense to declare a variable and then not use it. That's the case for `pp` and compiler is alerting that. In this particular case,

- either you use `pp` in some *required* way, or
- use it in the "no-op" way.

Following is the code for "no-op" way:

```
int main() {

    int compteur = 1;
    int *p = &compteur;
    int **pp = &p;
    (void) pp;            // no-op use of pp
}
```

For further details on no-op use, see the other thread: [What does the following code do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986295/what-does-the-following-code-do)